# Getting errors with /hardware/qcom/media-caf/msm8916

Tags: android, c++, linux, android-source, cyanogenmod

I'm trying to build a CM 14.1 ROM for the LG K7, but I'm encountering many problems while compiling. My device has a MSM8909 chip but it goes for MSM8916-caf variants. I don't know if it's kernel problem or not. I'm using the Kernel Source from LGE OpenSource (LGMS330)  Here's the error code:

Here's the device tree used: https://github.com/TheOddTaco/android_device_lge_m1-common

```
hardware/qcom/media-caf/msm8916/mm-video-v4l2/vidc/vdec/src/omx_vdec_msm8974.cpp:2068:18: error: use of undeclared identifier 'V4L2_CID_MPEG_VIDC_VIDEO_PRIORITY'; did you mean 'V4L2_CID_MPEG_VIDC_VIDEO_ROTATION_90'?
    control.id = V4L2_CID_MPEG_VIDC_VIDEO_PRIORITY;
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                 V4L2_CID_MPEG_VIDC_VIDEO_ROTATION_90
out/target/product/ms330/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/usr/include/linux/v4l2-controls.h:655:2: note: 'V4L2_CID_MPEG_VIDC_VIDEO_ROTATION_90' declared here
        V4L2_CID_MPEG_VIDC_VIDEO_ROTATION_90 = 1,
        ^
hardware/qcom/media-caf/msm8916/mm-video-v4l2/vidc/vdec/src/omx_vdec_msm8974.cpp:2069:21: error: use of undeclared identifier 'V4L2_MPEG_VIDC_VIDEO_PRIORITY_REALTIME_DISABLE'
    control.value = V4L2_MPEG_VIDC_VIDEO_PRIORITY_REALTIME_DISABLE;
                    ^
hardware/qcom/media-caf/msm8916/mm-video-v4l2/vidc/vdec/src/omx_vdec_msm8974.cpp:4505:22: error: use of undeclared identifier 'V4L2_CID_MPEG_VIDC_VIDEO_PRIORITY'; did you mean 'V4L2_CID_MPEG_VIDC_VIDEO_ROTATION_90'?
        control.id = V4L2_CID_MPEG_VIDC_VIDEO_PRIORITY;
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                     V4L2_CID_MPEG_VIDC_VIDEO_ROTATION_90
out/target/product/ms330/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/usr/include/linux/v4l2-controls.h:655:2: note: 'V4L2_CID_MPEG_VIDC_VIDEO_ROTATION_90' declared here
        V4L2_CID_MPEG_VIDC_VIDEO_ROTATION_90 = 1,
        ^
hardware/qcom/media-caf/msm8916/mm-video-v4l2/vidc/vdec/src/omx_vdec_msm8974.cpp:4507:29: error: use of undeclared identifier 'V4L2_MPEG_VIDC_VIDEO_PRIORITY_REALTIME_ENABLE'; did you mean 'V4L2_MPEG_VIDC_VIDEO_VPX_ERROR_RESILIENCE_ENABLED'?
            control.value = V4L2_MPEG_VIDC_VIDEO_PRIORITY_REALTIME_ENABLE;
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                            V4L2_MPEG_VIDC_VIDEO_VPX_ERROR_RESILIENCE_ENABLED
out/target/product/ms330/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/usr/include/linux/v4l2-controls.h:925:2: note: 'V4L2_MPEG_VIDC_VIDEO_VPX_ERROR_RESILIENCE_ENABLED' declared here
        V4L2_MPEG_VIDC_VIDEO_VPX_ERROR_RESILIENCE_ENABLED = 1,
        ^
hardware/qcom/media-caf/msm8916/mm-video-v4l2/vidc/vdec/src/omx_vdec_msm8974.cpp:4509:29: error: use of undeclared identifier 'V4L2_MPEG_VIDC_VIDEO_PRIORITY_REALTIME_DISABLE'
            control.value = V4L2_MPEG_VIDC_VIDEO_PRIORITY_REALTIME_DISABLE;
                            ^
hardware/qcom/media-caf/msm8916/mm-video-v4l2/vidc/vdec/src/omx_vdec_msm8974.cpp:4522:22: error: use of undeclared identifier 'V4L2_CID_MPEG_VIDC_VIDEO_OPERATING_RATE'; did you mean 'V4L2_CID_MPEG_VIDC_VIDEO_ROTATION_NONE'?
        control.id = V4L2_CID_MPEG_VIDC_VIDEO_OPERATING_RATE;
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                     V4L2_CID_MPEG_VIDC_VIDEO_ROTATION_NONE
out/target/product/ms330/obj/KERNEL_OBJ/usr/include/linux/v4l2-controls.h:654:2: note: 'V4L2_CID_MPEG_VIDC_VIDEO_ROTATION_NONE' declared here
        V4L2_CID_MPEG_VIDC_VIDEO_ROTATION_NONE = 0,
        ^
hardware/qcom/media-caf/msm8916/mm-video-v4l2/vidc/vdec/src/omx_vdec_msm8974.cpp:9326:14: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MSM_VIDC_BT709_5'
        case MSM_VIDC_BT709_5:
             ^
hardware/qcom/media-caf/msm8916/mm-video-v4l2/vidc/vdec/src/omx_vdec_msm8974.cpp:9330:14: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MSM_VIDC_BT470_6_M'
        case MSM_VIDC_BT470_6_M:
             ^
hardware/qcom/media-caf/msm8916/mm-video-v4l2/vidc/vdec/src/omx_vdec_msm8974.cpp:9333:14: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MSM_VIDC_BT601_6_625'
        case MSM_VIDC_BT601_6_625:
             ^
hardware/qcom/media-caf/msm8916/mm-video-v4l2/vidc/vdec/src/omx_vdec_msm8974.cpp:9336:14: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MSM_VIDC_BT601_6_525'
        case MSM_VIDC_BT601_6_525:
             ^
hardware/qcom/media-caf/msm8916/mm-video-v4l2/vidc/vdec/src/omx_vdec_msm8974.cpp:9340:14: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MSM_VIDC_GENERIC_FILM'
        case MSM_VIDC_GENERIC_FILM:
             ^
hardware/qcom/media-caf/msm8916/mm-video-v4l2/vidc/vdec/src/omx_vdec_msm8974.cpp:9343:14: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MSM_VIDC_BT2020'
        case MSM_VIDC_BT2020:
             ^
hardware/qcom/media-caf/msm8916/mm-video-v4l2/vidc/vdec/src/omx_vdec_msm8974.cpp:9346:14: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MSM_VIDC_UNSPECIFIED'
        case MSM_VIDC_UNSPECIFIED:
             ^
hardware/qcom/media-caf/msm8916/mm-video-v4l2/vidc/vdec/src/omx_vdec_msm8974.cpp:9357:14: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MSM_VIDC_TRANSFER_BT709_5'
        case MSM_VIDC_TRANSFER_BT709_5:
             ^
hardware/qcom/media-caf/msm8916/mm-video-v4l2/vidc/vdec/src/omx_vdec_msm8974.cpp:9358:14: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MSM_VIDC_TRANSFER_601_6_525'
        case MSM_VIDC_TRANSFER_601_6_525: // case MSM_VIDC_TRANSFER_601_6_625:
             ^
hardware/qcom/media-caf/msm8916/mm-video-v4l2/vidc/vdec/src/omx_vdec_msm8974.cpp:9361:14: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MSM_VIDC_TRANSFER_BT_470_6_M'
        case MSM_VIDC_TRANSFER_BT_470_6_M:
             ^
hardware/qcom/media-caf/msm8916/mm-video-v4l2/vidc/vdec/src/omx_vdec_msm8974.cpp:9364:14: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MSM_VIDC_TRANSFER_BT_470_6_BG'
        case MSM_VIDC_TRANSFER_BT_470_6_BG:
             ^
hardware/qcom/media-caf/msm8916/mm-video-v4l2/vidc/vdec/src/omx_vdec_msm8974.cpp:9367:14: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MSM_VIDC_TRANSFER_SMPTE_240M'
        case MSM_VIDC_TRANSFER_SMPTE_240M:
             ^
hardware/qcom/media-caf/msm8916/mm-video-v4l2/vidc/vdec/src/omx_vdec_msm8974.cpp:9370:14: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MSM_VIDC_TRANSFER_LINEAR'
        case MSM_VIDC_TRANSFER_LINEAR:
             ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
build/core/ninja.mk:151: recipe for target 'ninja_wrapper' failed
make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Lets take: V4L2_CID_MPEG_VIDC_VIDEO_ROTATION_90, you are missing this symbol which mean whoever used it had this in his kernel-headers

I would look at other project's hardware/qcom/msm8916/kernel-headers/...

I'm also downvoting this question as its more of 'asking-for-help' then a question other can benefit!

I think it could be best if you just ask a specific question on one of your specific errors.